# Attach a User Role: "Admin" to single html element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have user roles that link in a custom AuthorizeAttribute above my controller.(I use Asp.net framework)

1. I want the admin user to enter the area where they would have got a 401 error.
   (removed some code to keep it simple)

```
[PermissionBaseAuthorize(Role = "super_admin")]
public ActionResult Details()
{
  return View()
}
```

2. Once that is done I want the admin user to only be able to edit the email field in the Customer details view for example and not any of the other fields in the form on this View.

Please help if there is a simpler way of doing it please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, you can use the class that inherit from AuthorizeAttribute, then check if login with `OnAuthorization`, then check the user role with `User.IsInRole("Admin")`
then you can use `AuthorizationContext` and `HttpContext` to send your error message and redirect...

here is the code you can start with:

```
public class PermissionBaseAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID") == null || !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("your url")
            ...
```

For question 2, you need to add some code like:

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
 {
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) <text>|</text>
     ...           
 }
```

I suggest you to take a look to the following tutorial it can help you.
[Role-Based Menus in MVC](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/role-based-menus-in-mvc/), but better to read full post from the beginning.

**Edit:**

Here is also some tutorial for using AuthorizationContext :
[Custom REST authorization in ASP.Net MVC](https://medium.com/@aslamhadi/custom-rest-authorization-in-asp-net-mvc-e49f6a3f092f)

Comment: Thank You, I appreciate it !

Comment: Please try, if work mark it as answered to be useful also for others !